# Redirect to different upstream on error using nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, server, uwsgi

**Description**

I have two different services/servers running locally, one uses php5.6-fpm running on port 9000, the other is uwsgi running on port 5000, I would like to be able to stop php5.6-fpm and have the request be redirected to the uwsgi service.

```
upstream phpfpm {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=5s;
}

upstream darkapp {
    server 0.0.0.0:5000 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=5s;
}



server {
    listen 2000;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 5s;
        error_page 404 502 = /dark/home;
        #error_page 404 = @fallback;
    }

    #location @fallback
    location = /dark/home {
        #include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass darkapp;
        #proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    }
}

server {
    listen 4000;

    location / { 
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass darkapp;
    }
}
```

**Note**

I am able to access php applications on port 2000 until I manually stop the fpm service, I am also able to access the python application on port 4000.

**What Happens**

When I stop php-fpm and I try to access a site on port 2000 through my browser, I get the following when i DON'T INCLUDE uwsgi_params

```
2019/02/04 14:27:54 [error] 21062#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /info/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:2000"


2019/02/04 14:27:54 [error] 21062#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /info/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://0.0.0.0:5000", host: "localhost:2000"
```

Also the Uwsgi process which runs a flask app gives the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2287, in wsgi_app
    ctx = self.request_context(environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2204, in request_context
    return RequestContext(self, environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 284, in __init__
    self.url_adapter = app.create_url_adapter(self.request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2021, in create_url_adapter
    subdomain=subdomain)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1344, in bind_to_environ
    environ['REQUEST_METHOD'], path_info,
KeyError: 'REQUEST_METHOD'
```

When i DO INCLUDE uwsgi params, it redirects to / and I get the following

```
2019/02/04 14:42:34 [error] 22493#0: *43 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /info/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:2000"
2019/02/04 14:42:34 [error] 22493#0: *43 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:2000"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the return directive to pass the request to the server block that is listening to the uwsgi process

```
upstream phpfpm {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=5s;
}

upstream darkapp {
    server 0.0.0.0:5000 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=5s;
}



server {
    listen 2000;
    index index.php;
    root /var/www/html;
    location ~ \.php$ { 

        fastcgi_pass phpfpm;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 5s;
        error_page 403 404 502 = @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
        return 301 http://$host:4000/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 4000;

    location / { 
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass darkapp;
    }
}
```